# FlatList is slow on updating an individual item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

In my app I have a very long list of items. Here is what a single item looks like:

```
{
  "id": "3f05a9a7-3365-49bb-9879-c42b58c0f615",
  "title": "Joviold",
  "description": "adipisicing excepteur mollit occaecat excepteur labore Lorem excepteur proident ad"
}
```

Each item is rendered with a checkbox and can be toggled on and off. I keep the list of toggled items' ids in the `checkedItems` variable.

The problem is that whenever I press an item in the list, it takes a few seconds to toggle.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Card, Checkbox, Title, Paragraph } from 'react-native-paper';
import data from "./data";

const App = () => {
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState([]);

  const isChecked = (id) => {
    return checkedItems.includes(id);
  };

  const toggleItem = (id) => {
    if (isChecked(id)) {
      setCheckedItems(checkedItems.filter(item => item !== id));
    } else {
      setCheckedItems([...checkedItems, id]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={s.root}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toggleItem(item.id)}>
            <Card>
              <Card.Content style={s.content}>
                <Checkbox status={isChecked(item.id) ? "checked" : "unchecked"} />

                <View>
                  <Title>
                    {item.title}
                  </Title>

                  <Paragraph>
                    {item.description}
                  </Paragraph>
                </View>
              </Card.Content>
            </Card>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const s = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  content: {
    flexDirection: "row"
  }
});

export default App;
```

Try it out here: https://snack.expo.io/@pavermakov/flatlist-with-checkboxes

As you can see, there is nothing special in the code.The rendered items are lightweight. It shouldn't take that long to toggle an item.

What can I do to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

The first way to optimize is to take the render function out of the JSX and wrap it in a useCallback.

```js
const renderItem = useCallback(
({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toggleItem(item.id)}>
            <Card>
              <Card.Content style={s.content}>
                <Checkbox status={isChecked(item.id) ? "checked" : "unchecked"} />

                <View>
                  <Title>
                    {item.title}
                  </Title>

                  <Paragraph>
                    {item.description}
                  </Paragraph>
                </View>
              </Card.Content>
            </Card>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ), []
)
...

renderItem={renderItem}
```

You can [read more](https://dev.to/ltsharma/performance-optimisation-react-native-with-hooks-a77) here on this optimization and [more here](https://codingislove.com/optimize-react-native-flatlist-performance/).

Comment: It doesn't help much. I tried to reduce the number of rendered items down to 50. It looks like the list gets progressively slower as it grows. i thought that the number of items doesn't affect FlatList, because as far as I remember it doesn't render all items at once.